# Django Extending class based view dynamically

Tags: django, django-guardian

Is there a good way to dynamically choose which view I want to extend in my class based view in Django?

Right now I have 2 views(update and view) as follows that I would like to collapse into 1:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, DetailView
from guardian.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
 
class MyUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    permission_required = 'MyApp.change_mymodel'
    template_name = "MyApp/update.html"
    fields = ["name", "Type", "description"]

class MyDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    permission_required = 'MyApp.view_mymodel'
    template_name = "MyApp/view.html"
```

What I would like to do is have 1 view, and 1 url, and when the view is accessed if the user has the change permission, it should use UpdateView, if they have the view permission use DetailView, and if they have neither display some kind of error.

Is there a way to make that work?

**EDIT:  Final solution:**

```
class CombinedView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView, UpdateView):
model = MyModel
fields = ["name", "Type", "description"]

def get_required_permissions(self, request=None):
    if (self.request.user).has_perm('MyApp.change_mymodel', self.get_object()):
        return ['MyApp.change_mymodel']
    return ['MyApp.view_mymodel']

def get_template_names(self):
    if (self.request.user).has_perm('MyApp.change_mymodel', self.get_object()):
        return ["MyApp/update.html"]
    return ["MyApp/view.html"]
```

Comment: the `get_required_permissions()` method is checking the permissions using [***`user.has_perms()`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms) under the hood. So, You don't have to do the same in your ***if...elase*** clause.

Comment: What I understood from the OP is that you need to control the Detail and Update view behaviour based on the ***request method*** (because HTTP GET is used in DetailView and HTTP POST is used in UpdateView ). So, your solution ***may result in your expected behaviour, but I don't think it will not address the OP requirement in a Django way***

Comment: I am curious what the "django way" would be here.  If we both browse to somesite.com/something and  I have the change permission and you do not, then I should see the updateView class based view, and you should see the listView view.  My posted solution works, but I am curious why it isn't considered the django way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`get_template_names()`** method and **`get_required_permissions()`** method as,

```
class CombinedView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView, UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ["name", "Type", "description"]

    def get_required_permissions(self, request=None):  # alternate to `permission_required`
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return ['MyApp.change_mymodel']
        return ['MyApp.view_mymodel']

    def get_template_names(self):  # alternate to `template_name`
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return ["MyApp/update.html"]
        return ["MyApp/view.html"]
```

Comment: Getting a "CombinedView is missing a queryset" error now.  I'm also not following the request.method=="POST" lines.  These won't necessarily be POST requests, I just want to drop them into the change view if they have the change permission, that could still be a GET request, though I might be missing something there.

Comment: @user3246693 Updated the answer

Comment: doh!  Missed the model field.  That solved the queryset issue but the check for POST was still throwing it off.  You did however point me in the right diretion and I got it working now, will update the original post to include the final solution.  Thank you!!!

Comment: I think you can suggest the edits to my post, by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63007808/edit) it

Comment: Learned something else today!  Edit suggested